# Google Charts API - extracting data from another api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

I got a web api returning json such as:

```
[
  {
    "Week": 27,
    "Average": 9.42
  },
  {
    "Week": 28,
    "Average": 9.88
  }
]
```

It has specific parameters, such as id, startDate, endDate, returning me an Average for each week of the year in the given period of time. What I want, now, is to load this data into the google chart api to generate my chart for whatever ID , startDate, endDate I'm entering.

What have I tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Implementing Google Chart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartdetails_div" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        ID:        <br /> <input type="number" id="resultID" /> <br />
        Start date:<br /> <input type="date" id="startdate" /><br />
        End date: <br /> <input type="date" id="enddate" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Genereaza chart" id="generate" />
    </div><br />
    <div id="chart_div" />


    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {


            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

            function drawBasic() {

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('number', 'Week number');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Mark average');

                $('#generate').on("click", function () {
                    var uri = 'http://localhost:50492/questionnaires/' + $('#resultID').val() +
                '/statistics/start=' + $('#startdate').val()
                + '/end=' + $('#enddate').val();
                    $.getJSON(uri, function (average) {
                        data.addRows(average);

                        });
                    });




                var options = {
                    title: 'Mark Average Throughout The Datetime',
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Week number',
                        viewWindow: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 52
                        }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Mark average (scale of 1-10)'
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                  document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the json is returned in an array, you'll need to convert it to a format google can use

and need to wait until the data is returned, before drawing the chart

should look something like...

```
  // get json
  $.getJSON(uri, function (average) {
    // add data rows
    $.each( average, function(i, row) {
      data.addRow([row.Week, row.Average]);
    });

    // chart options
    var options = {
      title: 'Mark Average Throughout The Datetime',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Week number',
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: 52
        }
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Mark average (scale of 1-10)'
      }
    };

    // draw chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div')
    );
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
```

also, you can depend on the google `callback` to know when the page is ready

you could also provide default values, in order to display a chart when the page first loads

overall, recommend setting up the code something like this...

```
<div id="chartdetails_div" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
    ID:        <br /> <input type="number" id="resultID" /> <br />
    Start date:<br /> <input type="date" id="startdate" /><br />
    End date: <br /> <input type="date" id="enddate" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Genereaza chart" id="generate" />
</div><br />
<div id="chart_div" />


<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
      // set generate event
      $('#generate').on("click", drawBasic);

      // draw default chart
      drawBasic();

      function drawBasic() {
        // set default dates
        var currentDay = new Date();
        var lastMonth = new Date(
          currentDay.getFullYear(),
          currentDay.getMonth() - 1,
          currentDay.getDate()
        );

        // date formatter
        var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
          pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        });

        // use default values for first load
        var resultID = $('#resultID').val() || '1';
        var startdate = $('#startdate').val() || dateFormat.formatValue(lastMonth);
        var enddate = $('#enddate').val() || dateFormat.formatValue(currentDay);
        $('#resultID').val(resultID);
        $('#startdate').val(startdate);
        $('#enddate').val(enddate);

        // build uri
        var uri = 'http://localhost:50492/questionnaires/' + resultID +
                  '/statistics/start=' + startdate +
                  '/end=' + enddate;

        // build data table
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Week number');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Mark average');

        // get json
        $.getJSON(uri, function (average) {
          // add data rows
          $.each( average, function(i, row) {
            data.addRow([row.Week, row.Average]);
          });

          // chart options
          var options = {
            title: 'Mark Average Throughout The Datetime',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Week number',
              viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 52
              }
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'Mark average (scale of 1-10)'
            }
          };

          // draw chart
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
            document.getElementById('chart_div')
          );
          chart.draw(data, options);
        });
      }
    },
    packages: ['corechart']
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've fixed it using some random data to generate my chart. Exactly the same way U suggested, thank you very much, sir !

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you provided I am guessing you don't get any data in the google chart.

When your data is coming from an api you need to make sure you HAVE it before you try to USE it. This is a perfect place to use a JavaScript promise which will make your code wait until you have the api data and only then try to populate the google chart. Otherwise javascript will keep executing and your data object will be null UNTIL the api call completes which is basically too late for your chart.

Here is an article on promises to get you started : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

If you need to investigate what comes back from your service call you could just add a breakpoint statement in your call and then have a look and see what's in your response data.

```
$.getJSON(uri, function (average) {
                        debugger;
                        data.addRows(average);

                        });
                    });
```

Comment: I am not getting the data correctly, this would  be my first issue... then I guess it will be the one you mentioned.

Comment: that you can investigate by adding a breakpoint in your api call to see what comes back. more details were added to the original answer

Comment: but what if I need to acces a specific property of "average" ? for example "number"... is it data.addRow(average.number) ? Should that work ?